# How to fix : " ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')."?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using anaconda navigator. My dataset contains empty fields. I tried to remove it still there is the error: "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')."

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
X = pd.read_csv("f.csv")
y= pd.read_csv("target.csv")
print (X.head())
print(X.columns)
print(X[u'screen_name'])

le=LabelEncoder()

for col in X.columns.values:

    if X[col].values.any()=='nan':
        X[col].values=0;
    if X[col].dtypes=='object':
        # data=X[col]
        #X.shape
        #le.fit(X[col])
        print("current column is ")
        print(col)
        print(X[col])
        X[col]=le.fit_transform(X[col])
        print("after tranformation")
        print(X[col]) 
mean_imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
mean_imputer = mean_imputer.fit(X)
imputed_df = mean_imputer.transform(X)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=6, n_jobs=1, verbose=2)
model = clf.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your Imputer tries to replace values with the string 'NaN'. The actual NaNs will still be in the data, causing the model to complain during fitting. Instead, try

`mean_imputer = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=0)`